# Ubuntu changes drive order with multiple HDDs

Tags: drive

My motherboard is GIGABYTE GA-890GPA-UD3H, and I have 4 internal HDDs. The first one (sda) contains various Ubuntu versions. Others HDDs contain Windows XP, Windows 7, and data. However the drive order changes when there is a kernel/software update (all the 4 HDDs are connected). After a reboot,  sda has become sdc. All the HDDs are repositioned.  Can someone please explain how and why this happens. Is there a way to stop this from changing?

Answer (score 1):

The drive are named (sda, b, ...) in the order they are ready for the system I think and it changes, mainly if you have usb ones. Anyways, if you mount them using UUID instead of sda, sdb, you will have no more problems as UUID are fixed.